# Kurier font, greek letters not displaying properly with siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx

Trying to use the `kurier` font along with the `siunitx` package via pdflatex. In math-mode, the font looks good, but when using `siunitx` with `detect-all` the Greek letters are not using the correct font. Below is an MWE and preview. Any help would be appreciated.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

Math: $\mu^{2}$ $\Omega$

siunitx: \qty{2}{\um} \qty{2}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE preview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX tells you that the symbols are not there:

```
LaTeX Info: Symbol \textmu not provided by
            font family kurierlc in TS1 encoding.
            Default family used instead on input line 217.
LaTeX Info: Symbol \textohm not provided by
            font family kurierlc in TS1 encoding.
            Default family used instead on input line 217.
```

You can repair the first by declaring the encoding subset of kurier, but the second would then be missing as it is really not in TS1, so you would have to take it from the place the math gets it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{kurierlc}{6}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textohm}
                     {{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\char"0A}}
                          
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

Math: $\mu^{2}$ $\Omega$

siunitx: \qty{2}{\um} \qty{2}{\ohm}

\bfseries \qty{2}{\um} \qty{2}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. My LaTeX log didn't give me the same messages as you though. Mine are along the lines of: 

```
LaTeX Info: Font shape OMX/kurierlc/mx/n has incorrect series value mx.
            It should not contain an m! Please correct it.
            Found on input line 11.
```

This is from pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt). 

Your LaTeX messages sound much more helpful. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) `  is not relevant, you need to tell the LaTeX version (it is at the begin of the log: `LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1`.  Did you really check the log-file? The messages are not shown on the terminal.

Comment: Right, didn't realize the log file and the "output" I see in vscode are not one-to-one. I do in fact see the messages in the log file. Good to know.